# How to set the default application to a windows app for pdf and html files in Ubuntu running on WSL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wanted to know how to make Adobe Acrobat installed on my Windows 11 as the default application to open PDF files for Ubuntu running via WSL.

I installed Calibre on Ubuntu (WSL) for managing my e-books. It opens my pdf files in GIMP (installed on Ubuntu). I want it to open in Adobe Acrobat DC.

A similar issue happens when I launch a Jupyter Notebook; It opens the html file in Tilix Terminal.